# Tie Javascript Events to KendoUI mobile ListView <li>

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using KendoUI and I need to `fire` some javascript events when the user touches each specific LI item. Is this possible? Here is how I am mapping them.. help!

Thanks in advance :) New to this.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group">
    <li><a data-role="button" data-click="runFunctionOne">Function One</a></li>
    <li><a data-role="button" data-click="runFunctionTwo">Function Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS::

```
functionOne() {
    alert("Function one pressed");
};

functionTwo() {
    alert("Function two pressed");
};
```

Comment: have you found a way yet? OnaBai's answer doesn't work and strake's answer requires the listview to be bound to a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible!

This is the JavaScript:

```
function runFunctionOne() {
    alert("Function one pressed");
};

function runFunctionTwo() {
    alert("Function two pressed");
};
```

You forgot the `function` keyword before the name of the function and the name of the function in the HTML was `runFunctionOne` and not `functionOne`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind you can also use the the [Kendo listview click event.](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/listview#click) Click the link to view the documentation. Argument "e" gives you access to the listview's dataItem which is a subset of the control's dataSource.

Like this

```
    $("#customerList").kendoMobileListView({
                                            dataSource: customerDataSource,
                                            template: '<a>${Company}<span class="k-status-text"> <br />${CustNo}</span></a>',
                                            dataType:"json",
                                            style: "inset",
                                            click: function(e){
                                                var index = $(e.item).index();
                                                var text= $(e.item).index();
                                                alert(e.dataItem.CustNo);
                                                // redirect to
                                                app.navigate("#overview-customer");


                                            },
                                            dataBound: function(e){
                                                alert("Ive been bound");
                                            }
                                        });
```